# Add a folder to an Android project (Delphi)

Tags: android, delphi, deployment, directory

When making Android apps with Delphi, I know how to use the Deployment Manager to add a file that I can access at runtime. But I need to add hundreds of files. Is there a way to add an entire folder instead of just individual files? Example use case: a language learning app with hundreds of pictures corresponding to vocabulary words.

Comment: File deployment is done by the `System.StartUpCopy.pas`. If you haven't already got a reference to that in the project.dpr, then add it yourself. You can also copy the `StartUpCopy.pas` to your project folder for debugging. Then you can make whatever modifications you need to, to that source to allow whatever it is that you need.

Comment: A better solution might be to develop a REST or Datasnap server, which your app can use to download all those images from, on it's first run.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is what worked for me:**

1. Get an aws.amazon.com account and store the data you need in an S3 bucket
2. Use the Object Inspector to place an AmazonConnectInfo on your form. Edit the Account Name and Account Key to your aws credentials. Make sure the 'Region' and 'Endpoints' match the region you selected on aws.amazon.com, ex: "ca-central-1" for the Region and "s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com" for the three EndPoints.
3. Use this code to play any audio file from the bucket:

   const
   BUCKET_NAME = 'name of your s3 bucket';

   procedure TForm1.FetchAndPlaySound;
   var
   s3: TAmazonStorageService;
   thefilestream : TFileStream;
   NameOfFile: String;

   begin

   NameOfFile := 'subfoldername/example.wav';

   thefilestream := TFileStream.Create(System.Ioutils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + 'Dynamite.wav',fmOpenWrite);

   s3:= TAmazonStorageService.Create(AmazonConnectionInfo1);

   try

   if s3.GetObject(BUCKET_NAME, NameOfFile, thefilestream ) then

   begin

   //Where 'dynamite.wav' is a placeholder file put in the local memory using the Deployment Manager, asset/internal

   MediaPlayer1.FileName := System.Ioutils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + 'Dynamite.wav';

   MediaPlayer1.Play;

   end

   else

   begin

   else ShowMessage('missing file: ' + NameOfFile) ;

   end;

   finally

   s3.Free;

   thefilestream.Free;

   end;